# 12.04 is slow after deleting Xauthority and reinstalling xorg?

Tags: xorg

I had a problem logging into the system and found a solution here.

But now I have another, after this is the system is slow. In my opinion it goes with the re-installation of `xorg`. When I try to open something it takes 3 times more time.

Can somebody help me but, without re-installing the system, it is the last solution?